# PHP DOM DOCUMENT cannot load file

Tags: php, dom, ascii, domdocument

All,

I am trying to load an XML file into DOM, but it fails due to the following reason:

1. Presence of the registered trademark `®` (R with Circle) in the file.

Basically, if it shows the trademark sign (R with a Circle) then DOM fails to load the file.

The Error that is displayed are:

```
encoder errorCData section not finished 
Premature end of data in tag elm line 12
```

When I check encoding of the file I get **ASCII**. If I physically remove that Character from the file, then everything works just fine.

I am loading the file using the following code:

```
$xml_dom = new DOMDocument();
$xml_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$result = $xml_dom->load($file);
```

`$result = ''` (empty) when it fails. But when I remove the trademark character and everything works, `$result = 1`

**Is there a way to ask DOM to ignore that character? Is that character supposed to show if encoding is ASCII?**. This file is not generated by me, so changing encoding at this point is not an option.... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that method:

```
$pageDom = new DomDocument();    
$searchPage = mb_convert_encoding($htmlUTF8Page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
@$pageDom->loadHTML($htmlUTF8Page);
```

Answer (score 0):

File encoding was changed to `PLAIN` and it fixed everything....